# Issues in Multi Websites magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have configured a multi website like bikestore. So right now i have a folder bikestore inside my main magento installation which contains `index.php` file and a `.htaccess` file. I have created few categories withen my bikestore website and i have the following url to access my bikestore website `http://localhost/magento/bikestore/`. and it shows me the home page with the bikestore categories however if i click on MAGENTO Home it takes me to following url `http://localhost/magento` instead of `http://localhost/magento/bikestore/` and when i click on any categories the url it takes me is as `http://localhost/magento/index.php/catalog/category/view/s/yamaha/id/11/` instead it should take me to this `http://localhost/magento/bikestore/index.php/catalog/category/view/s/yamaha/id/11/`.. I think I am missing some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, magento does not add storecodes to the URL, try changing the following setting:

```
System -> Configuration -> Web -> Url Options -> Add Store Code to Urls
```